# .NET MVC 4 WebAPI POST not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Core problem: GET works, POST doesn't.  I'm new to WebAPI so I'm probably doing something stupid, but I've poked around quite a bit on the 'net trying to figure out why this isn't working.

Fairly simple WebAPI C# app.  I've tried to get this down to very simple routes:

```cs
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Add a route where action is supplied, i.e. api/csv/LoadToSQL
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

Controller class:

```
public class CsvController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/csv
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/csv/name
    public string Get(string csvName)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST - api/csv/LoadToSQL
    // Load a CSV to SQL
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("LoadToSQL")]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoadToSQL(
        string storageAccount,
        string accessKey,
        string containerName,
        string csvFileName,
        string connectionString,
        string targetDatabaseName,
        string targetTableName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount blobStorage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount);
```

Start it up locally and connect Fiddler.  Try a GET; works:

[image: Fiddler GET output]

Try a POST - fails:

[image: Fiddler POST output]

My original implementation had just

```
    // POST - api/csv
    // Load a CSV to SQL
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(
```

but that didn't work so I started trying to add specific routes and verb decorations.

It just doesn't seem to see the POST action against this controller no matter what I do.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE - per answer below, the correct route to make this work is:

```
        // Add a route where action is supplied, i.e. api/csv/LoadToSQL
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{storageAccount}/{accessKey}/{containerName}/{csvFileName}/{connectionString}/{targetDatabaseName}/{targetTableName}"
        );
```

This shows all the parameters to the POST request.

Comment: you are expecting multiple parameters but your route only has one, so your method cannot be resolved.  Either add all the parameters to the route {storageAccount}/{accessKey}/etc..., or pass a single object that has the properties you need.

Comment: Can you please provide your sample post request ?

Comment: OK, like I said... something stupid.  THANK YOU @dbugger... That wss in fact it.  I was trying to pass the parameters as query parameters.  Will update the Route to show the fix that made this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your method to be more clear and clean if you like so

1- declare a class with your options

```
public class LoadToSqlData
{
   public string storageAccount {get; set;}
   public string accessKey {get; set;}
   public string containerName {get; set;}
   public string csvFileName {get; set;}
   public string connectionString {get; set;}
   public string targetDatabaseName {get; set;}
   public string targetTableName {get; set;}
}
```

2- Declare your method to be :

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ActionApi")]
[Route("api/Csv/LoadToSQL")]
public HttpResponseMessage LoadToSQL([FromBody]LoadToSqlData data)
```

Notice the usage of the `[Route],[ActionName]` and the `[FromBody]` attributes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works - as does the earlier suggestion, but this is probably a better way to go as the earlier responder noted.  I updated this to fix a minor error - the members of the class should be public.